# Node.js spawn process not working inside Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a server.js file in Node that calls python scripts as follows:

```
// call python scripts 
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var process = spawn('python',["test.py", function_args]);

process.stdout.on('data', function (data){
    res.json({
       "answer" : from_python
    })
});
```

This works perfectly when simply running node as usual:

```
node server.js
```

But when I place everything inside a docker container, the application never enters the process.stdout.on

Everything else works perfectly. I can serve static files, call express endpoints, etc. It is just the process that is not getting called.

I have tried placing child_process inside my package.json file as a dependency.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my_app_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my_desc",
  "author": "my_name",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

Note that running server.js is not the problem. This file runs the other pieces such as serving static files and exposing express endpoints. The problem seems to just be with the child_process not running. It is not that Python isn't getting called, it is that node will not even enter the process part of server.js.

Also note that the Python prints its output via stdout. Not sure of docker has an issue registering standard outputs.

Comment: Show your Dockerfile

Comment: Added Dockerfile to question.

Comment: If you manually run `node server.js` from within the container, does it work?

Comment: If I enter the container (using docker exec -it <container id> /bin/bash) I cannot start the server.js manually since the port is being used by Docker. Outside the container, running node server.js works perfectly.

Comment: Any logs? `docker logs [container_id]`... Does the app crash?

Comment: Logs only show the output I place from console.log in my server.js file. Nothing out of the ordinary. No errors, no crashes. Even the browser shows no errors inside inspect element console when calling the endpoint that houses the process function. It just doesn;t enter that function...the API call just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
FROM node:carbon
```

should be

```
FROM node:9.3
```

Carbon is the LTS (currently still 8.*.*). You are using libraries from latest v9.3.0.